# make radio button checked on click other idv

Tags: jquery, radio-button

Hi i am trying to make a a function in which i need to make the

> radio button checked
>
> according to the button attribute value

which should be equal to the radio button value.

below is my code

```
<table id="oustandingItems">
  <tr><th>Category</th></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="radio" name="mytest" value='124' /></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="radio" name="mytest" value="123"/></td></tr>
</table>


<button title ="124" class="findRow">Find Row</button>
<button title ="123" class="findRow">Find Row</button>



$(".findRow").click(function() { 
    var rad = $(this).attr('title');

    //alert($(this).attr('title'));
  var myValue = $('#oustandingItems').find('input[value=rad]').val()
   alert(myValue);

      //$("#myRow").val(myValue);
});
```

i need to make the radio button checked whos value will be equal to the  button title vale

> ```
> <button title ="124" class="findRow">Find Row</button>
> <button title ="123" class="findRow">Find Row</button>
> ```

but this is not working please suggest how can i achieve this

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use string concatenation to make use of the variable value `rad` else it searches for a input element with value `rad` instead of looking for the value stored in the variable `rad`

```
$('#oustandingItems').find('input[value=' + rad + ']').prop('checked', true)

var myValue = $('#oustandingItems').find('input[value=' + rad + ']').val()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2xbYp/)

Comment: Hi can you please also hlp me in 
$(this).css("border","1px solid black"); i have add this to make the click element highlighted it works but when i click on other element that also get highlighted , i need to highlight one element at at time